# How to connect linux libXy.so shared object deployment to gradle dependency

Tags: java, maven, gradle, embedded-linux, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm tidying a a CI chain between a C/C++ compiled shared object (.so) and a gradle build job which takes the shared object using some form of binding to interface with hardware, in an embedded linux / kiosk style environment. My client uses aws, including using maven repositories for publishing their java dependancies.

Component #1 - C/C++ .so component
  libXY.so >> output

Component #2 - Java component built under gradle
  input << libXY.so

I have a bitbucket pipeline correctly generating the shared object. I do not know how to deploy it using good practises. The current process which obviously follows bad practises and which predates me is to compile libXY.so on a developer machine and git add the libXY.so into a folder inside Component #2. Once libXY.so is git pushed into component #2 the rest of the CI system kicks off and runs unit tests etc and if successful generates an artifact.

example bitbucket pipeline to add libYX.so component to the CI system

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build
        image: atlassian/default-image:2
        caches:
          - YYXX
        script:
          - apt update
          - apt install cmake libabc-dev libcba-dev -y
          - cmake ..
          - make
        artifacts:
          - libXY.so
    - step:
        name: Publish
        image: atlassian/pipelines-awscli  # maybe maven?
        trigger: manual
        script:
          - echo "TODO make publish to maven / aws s3 ???"

definitions:
  caches:
    YYXX: /opt/custom_libs
```

Portion of Component #2 build.gradle retrieving dependencies remotely, but not the libXY.so. The com.CustomerName dependencies are being retrieved from private aws maven repos already, which is what I think I should mimic. com.CustomerName:javalibname maps to an aws folder

com/CustomerName/javalibname with a maven-metadata.xml and then folders for versions

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.CustomerName', name:'customerjavaapp', version:"${customerjavaappVersion}"
    compile group: 'org.openmuc', name: 'jrxtx', version: '1.0.1'
    compile 'org.json:json:20180813'
    compile 'xuggle:xuggle-xuggler:5.4'
    compile "com.CustomerName:javalibname:1.3.2-4"
    compile group: 'net.java.dev.jna', name: 'jna', version: '5.0.0'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.10.0'
}
```

Portion of Component #2 build.gradle Code which I believe is copying in the shared object located in the code repository in order to deploy inside the .jar

```
distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            into("CustomerName"){
                from "CustomerName/settings1.conf"
                from "CustomerName/settings1.conf"
            }
            into("deps"){
                from "shared/libXY.so"
            }
            from "CHANGELOG.md"
        }
    }   
}
```

I expect to build the bitbucket pipeline for component #1 to publish the libXY.so to a maven repository hosted on aws, and then alter the build.gradle to retrieve it